# Angular NvD3 Multichart is not working

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to create Multichart graph with Line and MultiBar Chart by using [Angularjs NvD3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/). I have to create Line graph but unable to showing Multibar chart, i think i make some mistake. Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AEU93DKvpDnHL92prwnb?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'multiChart',
            height: 450,
            margin : {
                top: 30,
                right: 60,
                bottom: 50,
                left: 70
            },
            color: d3.scale.category10().range(),
            //useInteractiveGuideline: true,
            duration: 500,
            xAxis: {
                tickFormat: function(d){
                    return d3.format(',f')(d);
                }
            },
            yAxis1: {
                tickFormat: function(d){
                    return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
                }
            },
            yAxis2: {
                tickFormat: function(d){
                    return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
                }
            }
        }
    };


    /***********Line*********/
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.data[0]={};
    $scope.data[0].key='Stream';
    $scope.data[0].yAxis=1;
    $scope.data[0].type='line';
    $scope.data[0].values=[];
     $scope.data[0].values[0]={};
    $scope.data[0].values[0].x=0;
    $scope.data[0].values[0].y=4;
     $scope.data[0].values[1]={};
    $scope.data[0].values[1].x=1;
    $scope.data[0].values[1].y=8;


  $scope.data[1]={};
    $scope.data[1].key='Stream2';
    $scope.data[1].yAxis=1;
    $scope.data[1].type='line';
    $scope.data[1].values=[];
     $scope.data[1].values[0]={};
    $scope.data[1].values[0].x=0;
    $scope.data[1].values[0].y=4;
     $scope.data[1].values[1]={};
    $scope.data[1].values[1].x=1;
    $scope.data[1].values[1].y=8;
    /*******************************/
    /********MultiBar Chart**********/
     $scope.data[2]={};
    $scope.data[2].key='Stream3';
    $scope.data[2].yAxis=2;
    $scope.data[2].type='multiBarChart';
    $scope.data[2].values=[];

     $scope.data[2].values[0]={};
    $scope.data[2].values[0].key="Stream0";
    $scope.data[2].values[0].values=[];
    $scope.data[2].values[0].values[0]={};
    $scope.data[2].values[0].values[0].key="Stream0";
    $scope.data[2].values[0].values[0].series=0;
    $scope.data[2].values[0].values[0].x=0;
    $scope.data[2].values[0].values[0].y=5;

     $scope.data[2].values[1]={};
    $scope.data[2].values[1].key="Stream1";
    $scope.data[2].values[1].values=[];
    $scope.data[2].values[1].values[0]={};
    $scope.data[2].values[1].values[0].key="Stream1";
    $scope.data[2].values[1].values[0].series=1;
    $scope.data[2].values[1].values[0].x=0;
    $scope.data[2].values[1].values[0].y=4;
    /*********************************/
    console.log($scope.data);


});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please find below plunkr with 
'multichart with configurable tooltip, conditional points highlight,area chart, bar chart and line chart

plunk in comments

Comment: Missing explanation on why the code above does not work and why the plunker example makes it work

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/nUPV1j2DzC70S3AQvSOU?p=preview

please find corrected code in above link. problem is you cannot say type of graph as 'multiBarChart' as there is no such graph type(multiBarChart is name given by nvd3 developers to the type of graph where you can have multiple types of graphs suvh as area, scatter,line and so on)